# Finding the average number of a has many association between two models using Rails ActiveRecord query interface

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Lets say I have two models: :User and :Ringtone. A :User can have many :Ringtones and a :Ringtone belongs to a user. I would like to be able to use the ActiveRecord Query interface to calculate the average number of :Ringtones that belongs to a :User, but am struggling to figure out how.

Using raw sql I can get the data like:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
            (with tones_count as 
                (select 
                user_id, count(ringtones.id)
                from 
                ringtones
                group by 1)
            select avg(count) from tones_count)").values
```

But this is not ideal, and I would much rather be able to use ActiveRecord for this query/calculation...

Comment: What you have here is fine. The ActiveRecord query interface is not great at doing anything more then the most trivial DB calculations and what you come up with will very likely be less performant or less readible.

Answer (score 0):

`I would much rather be able to use ActiveRecord`, you could do like so

```rb
    table = Arel::Table.new(:ringtones)
    Ringtone.from(
      Ringtone.select(
        table[:user_id], 
        table[:id].count.as("tones_count")
      ).group(1)
    ).average("tones_count")
```